# Узнать,какая часть скрипта занимает много времени на выполнение PHP

Tags: php, отладка

Есть ли способы,кроме расположения кучи `microtime` по всему скрипту,чтобы узнать какая часть кода занимает много времени при загрузке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классический ответ звучит так - использовать профайлер. Например, встроенный в xDebug. На [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script) есть много примеров. Профайлеры выдают хорошую статистику, по которой уже видно кто и как использует процессорное время.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё есть [newrelic](http://newrelic.com/).

Можно настроить демон на сервере, чтобы тот отсылал данные newrelic. В веб-интерфейсе newrelic`а можно будет посмотреть среднее время выполнения ваших функций, самые медленные функции, самые часто выполняемые.